# Firebase hosting build fails because process.env.ci is set to true

Tags: firebase, github-actions, firebase-hosting

I am trying to deploy a create-react-app to firebase hosting.

I followed the step in the Get Started guide, and got a github actions workflow set up for me.
It looks like so:

```
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm install && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_xxxxx }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: master
        env:
          FIREBASE_CLI_PREVIEWS: hostingchannels
          CI: false
```

However; when I push a new commit, the build fails because of
`Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.`

As you can see, I tried to fix this with adding `CI: false`, but `CI` is still being set to `true`. How can I fix this? And why is my attempt at solving this not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fix was to move `CI: false` above the `build_and_deploy` step:

```
env:
  CI: false

jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm install && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_xxxxx }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: xxxxxx
        env:
          FIREBASE_CLI_PREVIEWS: hostingchannels
```

Why are there 2 `env`'s? No idea. But it works.

Comment: ["You can define environment variables for a step, job, or entire workflow"](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables). The top level `env` will apply to every step whereas the `env` in your example was only applying to the `FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy` step and not the step that included `npm run build`.